# Need to start app immediately after the boot completed

Tags: java, android

I need to know why my app didn't run immediately after booting in android real phone? My app runs but after a few second of booting.

My Code is

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
    }

}
```

My activity is running, but after few Seconds of the boot completed. Is it Possible to reduce this few second?

I want to run my app immediately. I Don't want to allow user to access the phone.

Comment: You cannot reduce the time of the application taking to launch after the boot. The OS of the phones prepares the storage and executes the services and processes including the application set on the boot completion. It will take some time, as it also depends on the memory (RAM) of the phone. Higher the RAM quickly the applications and services will launch.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can increase you **priority** but still there would be some delay. Since android first load its OS and the all the other activity starts.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AutoStart"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: So, what is the highest priority possible? And if another application has the same priority, isn't this flag will be useless?

Comment: The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000. from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Comment: Does  the highest priority is: 2147483647 ?

Answer (score 3):

I run through this problem too. To anyone still searching for solution:

> I want to run my app immediately. I Don't want to allow user to access the phone.

Consider turning your app into home launcher. Make changes in the manifest:

Add to your activity

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Add to intent filter in activity

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

After that it will launch immediately with system, not showing to user anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Android system does lot of work on boot completed. 
hence the intent might be delayed. Depending on the phone capabilities, the intent delay times will vary.